# Getting User Registration Date

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mean-stack

so I have a mongoDB that is storing a date.now variable which is returning the current date. I would like the user database to store the date on which the users registered. Is there any way I can do that? I am assuming by using the Date() in JS but I am not entirely sure where I would place that when all of my database information is coming from a form and I do not want the user to see this.

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
    firstName: {type: String, required: true, validate: nameValidator},
    lastName: {type: String, required: true, validate: nameValidator},
    addressOne: {type: String, required: true, validate: addressValidator},
    addressTwo: {type: String, validate: addressTwoValidator},
    city: {type: String, required: true, validate: cityValidator},
    state: {type: String, required: true, validate: stateValidator},
    zipcode: {type: String, required: true, validate: zipValidator},
    country: {type: String, required: true, validate: countryValidator},
    registrationDate: {type: String, default: Date.now}

 });

    <input type="hidden" name="registrationDate"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getDate() {
            var today = new Date();
            var dd = today.getDate();
            var mm = today.getMonth()+1;
            var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
            if(dd<10){dd='0'+dd} if(mm<10){mm='0'+mm};
            var output = today.toDateString();
            return output
        }
        getDate();
    </script>

    var user = new User();
    user.firstName = req.body.firstName;
    user.lastName = req.body.lastName;
    user.addressOne = req.body.addressOne;
    user.addressTwo = req.body.addressTwo;
    user.city = req.body.city;
    user.state = req.body.state;
    user.zipcode = req.body.zipcode;
    user.country = req.body.country;
    user.registrationDate = req.body.registrationDate;
```

Comment: I am trying to send it as hidden form data but for some reason my data base is not populating, I am assuming something with my function is broken?

Comment: There shouldn't be an issue if you're sending it as hidden form data. Something is probably broken. Are you able to link more code?

Comment: just updated my post with the date function I am using

Comment: You should be saving your date as a datetime in your db. It will make things easier in the long run.

Comment: above in the user schema.
registrationDate: {type: String, default: Date.now} 
that is how its being passed, I also edited the post with the post data